# Do I need to take the IELTS test if I immigrate from a primarily english speaking country?

Tags: australia, usa, ielts

I'm currently contemplating moving from the United States to Australia (Queensland). I read that one of the immigration requirements was to complete the [IELTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_English_Language_Testing_System) test.

Because I'm already from a primarily english-speaking country, do I receive any exemptions? Is the test waived entirely?

Comment: Which visa are you considering applying for?

Comment: I haven't looked at Australia, but I have seen other governments which waive language tests if one has a university degree from an English-speaking country; you might search from that point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this webpage](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/meeting-our-requirements/english-language/competent-english), just having a USA passport is enough to guarantee "competent English."

I reached that page by following the pages that discuss applying for permanent residency based on points-based work visa.

One possibility for taking the test anyway is if you need some points.